# The square of an algebraic number is also algebraic

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, field-theory

I'm trying to prove that if $x$ is an algebraic number then $x^2$ must also be.

It seems intuitive but I just can't find any kind of proof as I keep running into equations with fractional exponents that don't fit the definition. Any help please?

Comment: maybe use the fact that algebriac numbers are solutions to a polynomial equation ,then subtitue $x$ by $\sqrt{x}$

Comment: @Jack, do you know some fields extensions theory?

Comment: I tried that substitution but the resulting equations had fractional exponents which I didn't think fit the definition of a polynomial and therefor algebraic. No I don't know about field extension theory sorry.

Answer (score 7):

The number $x$ is algebraic if it is the root of a polynomial equation $p(x)=0$

Now set $y=x^2$ so that $p(x)=q(y)+xr(y)$ with $q(y), r(y)$ both polynomials.

Then $y$ is a root of $$\left(q(y)+xr(y)\right)\cdot\left(q(y)-xr(y)\right)=q^2(y)-x^2r^2(y)=q^2(y)-yr^2(y)=0$$which is a polynomial equation in $y$.